# How to integrate custom scripts regarding bbl & idx files in latexmkrc

Tags: latexmk

For compiling my tex files into pdfs, a dos batch file named `makepdf.bat` is used like this:

```
set name=mybook

xelatex %name% -synctex=1
bibtex %name%


iconv -f utf-8 -t gbk %name%.bbl>%name%.bbl.bak
del %name%.bbl
ren %name%.bbl.bak %name%.bbl
replace_fs %name%.bbl ]//. ]//
fixbbl -cjk -sort=pinyin %name%
iconv -f gbk -t utf-8 %name%.bbl>%name%.bbl.bak
del %name%.bbl
ren %name%.bbl.bak %name%.bbl

iconv -f utf-8 -t gbk %name%.idx>%name%.idx.bak
del %name%.idx
ren %name%.idx.bak %name%.idx
cctmkind -s entropy.ist -C mixed %name%
iconv -f gbk -t utf-8 %name%.ind>%name%.ind.bak
del %name%.ind
ren %name%.ind.bak %name%.ind


xelatex %name% -synctex=1
xelatex %name% -synctex=1

del *.log *.aux *.bbl *.bbl.bak *.out *.thm *.toc *.log *.idx *.ind /s

start "D:\Tools\sumatrapdf\SumatraPDF" %name%.pdf -reuse-instance
exit
```

In the above batch file,

1. A few of `bbl` and `idx` files were generated by the first xelatex command.
2. For some reason regarding files' encoding, they have to be converted from utf-8 encoding to gbk by using `iconv`.
3. The resulting gbk encoded files are processed by special tools such as `replace_fs`, `fixbbl`, `cctmkind` and then converted back to utf-8 encoding.
4. Run `xelatex` again and open the pdf file in SumtraPDF.

Due to knowing few about `latexmk` and perl, I have no idea on how to tranlate this bat file into a `latexmkrc` format. Can anybody help me with this trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create your own batch files to run instead of `bibtex` and `makeindex`.  Let's call them `mybibtex.bat` and `mymakeindex.bat`.  Then you configure `latexmk` to use these instead of the standard programs, e.g., by

```
$bibtex = 'mybibtex %R';
$makeindex = 'mymakeindex %R';
```

One implementation for these batch files is as follows:  You start with `mybibtex.bat` having everything in the original batch file from the `bibtex` line to the rename command that gives the final `bbl` file.  Similarly `mymakeindex.bat` contains the next block of commands, the ones that process the index.  Then, in these files, you change `%name%` to `%1` to correspond to the first argument of the batch file.

There are fancier solutions within `latexmk`, using a defined Perl subroutine: see the section "FORMAT OF COMMAND SPECIFICATIONS" in the `latexmk` documentation.  But the invoked batch file solution is fine (and you can invoke the batch files yourself or from other batch files).